# Taylor Expansion Analysis

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I have been given a "help function" (direct translated) $g(t)=\ln(2+t)$, for $|t|< 1$. Show that:
$$ \biggl|g(t)-\Bigl(\ln(2)+\frac{t}{2}\Bigr)\biggr| \leq \frac{1}{2}t^2$$
For all $|t|\leq 1$. I am a bit lost here as it does not look like an exercise we previously have solved. Normally I would evaluate the remainder and see that it is less than $\frac{M_n}{(n+1)!}|x-x_0|^{n+1}$. However, it does not seem possible in this assignment. We have also been given a function $f(x)=\ln(2+x^3) \ , \ |x|\leq1$ where I've found $T_3(x)=\ln(2)+1/2 x^3$. I cannot see how this would help me here though...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Rewrite $g(t)=\ln2\bigl(1+\frac t2\bigr)=\ln 2+\ln\bigl(1+\frac t2\bigr)$ and observe that 
$$\ln\Bigl(1+\frac t2\Bigr)=\frac t2-\frac{t^2}8+\frac{t^3}{24}-\dotsm$$
is an alternating series for $0<t<1$, so you can apply Leibniz' estimate for the error.

If $-1<t<0$, it is still more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it makes sense to me. However, we are not alllowed to use Leibniz' estimate for error as we have not proved it yet. Is there another method to solve this problem?